# Why is CSS not positioning correctly?

Tags: css

I have designed picture 1 in PhotoShop which is what I was planning in the HTML.

I added the float to all elements but for some reason I don't understand it starts breaking the divs (picture 2)... am I missing something obvious here?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<div style="width: 974px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: white; padding: 0px;border: 0px solid black;">
    <div style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; float: left;border: 1px solid black;">
        <a href="/Main/">
            <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/7qbv2a6jd/tb_logo_site3.png" width="180" height="86" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;margin-top:10px;border: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/h8bm2bs7t/patreon_site3.png" width="280" height="42" />
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:35px;margin-left:60px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/q9uqtofix/poster_1_site3.png" width="300" height="496" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/h9ljvqu1l/paper_soho_title_site3.png" width="400" height="114" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/mfwp6s8t5/fist_page_icon_site3.png" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">

        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/4m175hpqx/first_page_site3.png" />
    </div>


    <div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/7mi1m1121/last_page_icon_site3.png" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">

        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/6vpbg8yop/last_page_site3.png" />
    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Although I think it's a bad practice, I've seen simple websites that are a single image that have an image-map, you could try that since you've mostly done everything in photoshop anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment is off because of the size of `Read From First Page` and `Jump To Last Page` images. Giving width to the images will place it to the side of left container.

Also use `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle` to align the container vertically into middle.

Here is the link that explains the use of `display:inline-block`

http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/

Have modified your html code

```
<div style="width: 974px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: white; padding: 0px;border: 0px solid black;">
    <div style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; float: left;border: 1px solid black;">
    <a href="/Main/">
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/7qbv2a6jd/tb_logo_site3.png" width="180" height="86">
    </a>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;margin-top:10px;border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/h8bm2bs7t/patreon_site3.png" width="280" height="42">
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:35px;margin-left:60px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/q9uqtofix/poster_1_site3.png" width="300" height="496">
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/h9ljvqu1l/paper_soho_title_site3.png" width="400" height="114">
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/mfwp6s8t5/fist_page_icon_site3.png">
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;height: 100%;display: inline-block;">

    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/4m175hpqx/first_page_site3.png" style="
    width: 230px;">
    </div>


    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;vertical-align: middle;">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/7mi1m1121/last_page_icon_site3.png">
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border: 1px solid black;">

    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/6vpbg8yop/last_page_site3.png" style="
    width: 230px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have way too many divs, and you gotta adjust the margins/paddings.
Take a look at [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)..